# Error opening device /dev/sysdig0: make sure sysdig-probe module is loaded

Tags: arch-linux, monitoring, manjaro

I'm running `Linux 4.16.8-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I've installed the `sysdig` package, and trying to run it, I see:

```
$ sudo sysdig
Unable to load the driver
error opening device /dev/sysdig0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the sysdig-probe module is loaded.
```

How do I load the required module on Arch-based Manjaro Linux?

Comment: There were once some bugs in ARM. Would you care adding technical details?

Comment: Run `sysdig-probe-loader` to load the kernel module , as root run `sysdig`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added.

Comment: @GAD3R I get a message saying precompiled module `https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.draios.com/stable/sysdig-probe-binaries/sysdig-probe-0.21.0-x86_64-4.16.8-1-MANJARO-c16b3360877c0c3271d78341a59b8f74.ko` can't be downloaded.  The link is to an XML file saying "access deined'

Comment: Hmm, given there is a package for it, I raised it [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/load-sysdig-probe-on-x86-64/48006) on the Manjaro Forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install the kernel headers:

```
sudo pacman -S linux416-headers
```

As part of this process, the `sysdig` module was installed:

```
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/3) Updating linux416 module dependencies...
(2/3) Install DKMS modules
==> dkms install sysdig/0.21.0 -k 4.16.8-1-MANJARO
```